# Existence of limit point & compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $\tau =\{\varnothing\}\cup\{\mathbb{R}-X\,|\, X\text{ is countable}\} $ be a topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the product $Y=\mathbb{R}\times\{0,1\}$ with the product topology, where $\{0,1\}$ is discrete.

1. Show that any proper infinite subspace of $Y$ has a limit point.
2. Is $Y$ compact?

---

I honestly cannot wrap my head around this. Any tips are welcome!

Comment: Of course, go back to the definitions. What do subbasic and basic open sets look like?

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand why they ask about the product space rather than $U=(\Bbb R,\tau)$: the answers can basically only be "because this occurs in $U$" and "yes/no because $U$ is/isn't".

Comment: @Gae.S. Doesn't closure only imply that the set's limit points belong to the set?

Comment: @Zuy Yeah, but $\{(n,0)\,:\, n\in\Bbb N\}$ is closed and the subspace topology is discrete, therefore no limit points. Anyway, I'll write an answer.

Comment: @Gae.S. This makes sense, thanks.

Comment: $\{0,1\}$ should be indiscrete/trivial, I think.. Then 1 is correct which it is not for a discrete factor.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma How to see that 1 will be correct then? I checked, and the problem says discrete though. Maybe this is a typo.

Comment: With indiscrete second factor and if $(a,0) \in A$, $(a,1)$ will be a limit point of $A$, as then any neighbourhood of $(a,1)$ contains $(a,0)$ too, etc.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Where would you need that $A$ is infinite and proper?

Comment: You don't need that $A$ is infinite or proper. In that case **all** non-empty subsets $A$ have a limit point. The infinite is only asked because we want an example of a limit point compact space (that is not compact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $A=\Bbb N\times \{0\}$ has no limit points. In fact, let $x$ be a limit point. Since $A$ is closed, $x=(m,0)\in A$. On the other hand, if $x\in A$, then $U=((\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb N)\cup\{m\})\times \{0,1\}$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ such that $U\cap A=\{(m,0)\}$.
2. $(\Bbb R,\tau)\times \{0,1\}$ is compact if and only if either all factors are compact or one factor is empty. Both factors are non-empty and $(\Bbb R,\tau)$ is not compact because the family of closed sets $\mathcal F=\{[n,\infty)\cap \Bbb N\,:\, n\in\Bbb N\}$ satisfies $\bigcap \mathcal F=\emptyset$, while no finite subfamily has empty intersection. Therefore $Y$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

$2:$ To see that $Y$ is not compact, we need to create a cover that has no finite subcover. Let $U_1$ be an open set in $Y$ such that $U_1 = \mathbb{R}-X \times \{0,1\}$ where $X$ is a countably infinite set. Ennumerate the elements of $X$, $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}.$

Then $(\mathbb{R}-X)^c = X$ is a countable infinite set. Choose $U_2$ to be $U_1 \cup (\{x_1\} \times \{0,1\})$. So $U_2$ is just $U_1$ and we added in the first element of the ennumaration of $X$. Continuing this way we will build is an infinite sequence of nested intervals (which means $U_k \subset U_{k+1}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$) with no finite subcover. Thus $Y$ is not compact.